# OpenVPN slow over UDP

Tags: performance, openvpn, udp

I am trying to create a site-to-site connection using OpenVPN. The setup in general is operative: I can reach all servers from every node in each network. The bandwidth within networks is high (>1Gbps) and the link bandwidth to the Internet is acceptable (usually >100 Mbit/s on site1 and >300Mbit/s on site2, both symmetrical, measured against speedtest.net).

However, when writing data through the tunnel the data rate drops drastically to around 30 Mbit/s rendering any data transfer between sites quite tedious.

This is the basic call I used during my tests:

```
openvpn --remote X.X.X.X \
        --dev tun1 \
        --ifconfig 10.218.4.2 10.218.4.1 \
        --secret /root/secret.key \
        --verb 3 \
        --sndbuf 393216 \
        --rcvbuf 393216 \
        --route 10.216.0.0   255.255.0.0     10.218.4.1 \
        --route 10.35.32.0   255.255.255.0   10.218.4.1 \
        --route XXX.YYY.Z.88 255.255.255.255 10.218.4.1 \
        --route XXX.YYY.A.88 255.255.255.255 10.218.4.1 \
        --route XXX.YYY.Z.10 255.255.255.255 10.218.4.1 \
        --compress lz4
```

I fiddled around with different settings for `--sndbuf` and `--rcvbuf` but the changes in bandwidth were negligible.

Following the suggestions for gigabit links I found [here](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Gigabit_Networks_Linux), adding `--tun-mtu 60000 --fragment 0 --mssfix 0` resulted in a blazing speed across the tunnel (reaching >700 Mbit/s) from one endpoint to the other. However, bandwidth between servers inside the respective networks going through the tunnel did not improve at all. This is somewhat expected as the MTU in both networks remains at 1500 and the packets arriving at the gateways remain 'small'.

From what I read (and observe) the culprit is mainly OpenSSL performing significantly better on larger chunks of data. Since the chunks coming from either network are limited by the overall MTU, the performance of OpenSSL causes the bottleneck I observe. It is my understanding that this is consistent with the speed improvement between endpoints, since there the 'network' MTU of 60000 is used.

Resorting to the (sub-optimal) VPN-over-TCP did increase the bandwidth slightly. Given the (potential) drawbacks regarding link stability and problems of TCP-over-TCP however seem too sever to consider this an option.

I was unable to find any suggestion/solution of how to circumvent this limitation or how to improve UDP throughput and was wondering if this is a 'hard' limit that I've hit or if I am missing anything (obvious).

Comment: Which cipher do you use? As pointed out in the page that you linked in your question, this has a huge impact. Depending on your security requirements, you could choose a weaker, but faster encryption method (with the `--cypher` parameter).

Comment: For the above I use the default cipher (and OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips). However, changing to `aes-256-cbc` did not show much (if any) speed improvements.

Comment: Give it a shot with lowest encryption available. If speed boosted, crypto computation is the root of the evil. Take MTU and fragmentation more seriously. Sometimes routers cannot handle it that fast.